# Get associated object value from filter query using Realm swift

Tags: swift, realm

So Im pretty new to realm and i feel my question is very basic but i cant find the answer to it.

Basically I'm trying to query Realm for all `playerName` associated with a specific `TeamID` (ie. `TeamID` is not the primary key), however Im having trouble finding the solution. I keep getting a `Value of type 'Results<playerInfoTable>' has no member 'playerName'` error.

Below is my Realm class:
`class playerInfoTable: Object {

```
@objc dynamic var playerID: Int = 0
@objc dynamic var playerName: String = ""
@objc dynamic var jerseyNum: Int = 0
@objc dynamic var TeamID: String = ""
@objc dynamic var goalCount: Int = 0
@objc dynamic var shotCount: Int = 0

override class func primaryKey() -> String {
    return "playerID"
}
```

}`

And the Code I'm using the query Realm:

```
let mainPlayerFilter = NSPredicate(format: "teamID == %@", "1")
let mainPlayerStrings = realm.objects(playerInfoTable.self).filter(mainPlayerFilter)
let mainPlayerTeamName = mainPlayerStrings.playerName
```

**Solution!**

```
let mainPlayerFilter = NSPredicate(format: "TeamID == %@", String(homeTeam!))
let mainPlayerStrings = realm.objects(playerInfoTable.self).filter(mainPlayerFilter)
let mainPlayerTeamName = mainPlayerStrings.value(forKeyPath: "playerName") as! [String]
```

Comment: It's good you found a solution. However it will be meaningless to future readers as the homeTeam var is undefined so we don't know what it is. Additionaly you should consider creating a Team object that does have a primary key, and then store that key in each players properties. And/Or add a Payers List property to the Team object and associate each player with that team. Doing that would avoid queries completely as when you load the Team, you will have a link to all of that teams players within the players property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you get the error when you declare the mainPlayerTeamName constant. Try the following:

```
let mainPlayerTeamName = mainPlayerStrings.first?.playerName
```

And I noticed that in your playerInfoTable class you declare "teamID" as "TeamID", while in your predicate you refer to it as "teamID". Decide which one you want because NSPredicate is case sensitive by default.

Comment: Was looking for Realm to return a result based on all the `playerName`'s with a certain `TeamID` not juts the first one. I have updated my post with a solution, thanks though!